# How to use vuetify to send pdf/word document to .net core api

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've a form where fields are sending to API as json object. I need to add another field which would basically going to use vuetify upload file component to send file to server as a Json string. The idea is to store uploaded file into the database.

Below is my code:

```
<v-file-input @change="addUploadedfiles" v-mode="uploaded_file">
data() {retrun{formData : {status: 'new',subject: '', name: '', uploaded_file: []}}}
methods: addUploadedfiles(){this.uploaded_file.forEach((file)=>{file_content: this.uploaded_file});}

http.post("/submitform", this.data)
```

I want to send file as a base64 string something like blob we do for images but in this case for word/pdf documents. Is this possible? The back-end api is .net core 5

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to answer your, question, but I will format your code, so maybe someone else will:

```
<v-file-input @change="addUploadedfiles" v-mode="uploaded_file">

data() {
  retrun{
    formData: {
      status: 'new',
      subject: '',
      name: '',
      uploaded_file: [],
    }
  }
}

methods: {
  addUploadedfiles(){
    this.uploaded_file.forEach((file)=>{file_content: this.uploaded_file})
  }
}

http.post("/submitform", this.data)
```